# Cannot cast double as int

Tags: java, casting, floating-point

I'm having a problem in my script where it says I can't convert a double to an integer...

Here's the where the error is noted in the bat:

```
cm.getPlayer().yellowMessage("You have gained " + 
                getJQ.getCurrentMap() + " JQ points!");
```

The error is off of the method `getCurrentMap()`, which is here...

```
public int getCurrentMap() {
    return maps.get((level - 1));
}
```

Level is an integer that is incremented every time the player advances a level. What I don't understand is how I'm receiving that error. When I print out the `List<Integer> maps`, I get a list of numbers. I don't see what's wrong.

Here is how I declare it:

```
private int level = 0;
```

Image of Error:
[image: Bat Error]

Code:
[Code - Look at the methods getCurrentMap and the declaration of maps in the file. Ignore everything else.](http://pastebin.com/FF1QPN2z)

[Source Code: As you can see level is declared as an int, and getCurrentMap() only details with integers. There main lines that deal with this error are lines 29-32, and lines 59-61, where I push an array with a random value.](http://pastebin.com/yK1V1cm9)

Comment: What kind of error do you receive exactly?

Comment: Java doesn't use scripts, do you simply mean source code?

Comment: If `maps` is a `List<Integer>`, I don't see any place where you have a double in the first place to get an error when trying to cast.  Where is the double in your code?

Comment: Can you post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the stacktrace of your error?

Comment: My game uses JavaScript for non-source related things that can be updated without compiling the jar file.

Comment: Show how level is declared.

Comment: private int level = 0;

Comment: @Xari If you actually had no doubles in your code, you wouldn't be getting a cast error.  What you've shown so far won't generate the error you're describing.  You're going to need to create an mcve like RC suggested.

Comment: I'll retrieve the exact error of the bat now.

Comment: I added the code for the script.

Comment: You are assigning a double from JavaScript to `level`, it never even reached your Java code. Check the stack trace.

Comment: I never assign level to anything. I simply increment it with ++ whenever the stage advances. I also don't get why I'm being downvoted so much. I'm providing information as people ask, and I believe there's a lot to go off of now?

Comment: Meh, that's just SO being obnoxious, not giving you time to adjust. Ignore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `level` is a `double` then the result is a double as well. Java won't convert it to an integer because that would lose information. So you have to make it explicit:

```
return maps.get((int) (level - 1));
```

If `level` (or any other `int`) is retrieved from JavaScript, the code will not even be executed however. You are assigning a `double` from JavaScript to an `int`, so it never even reaches your Java code. Accept a double from JavaScript, then convert it to an integer by casting using `(int)`.

You may want to use `Math.ceil` first - or another rounding method - if you want to round up instead of down.

Comment: The issue is level is actually an int, so I don't see where a double is being used.

Comment: Are you sure? Java**Script** only knows doubles, not integers. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Maybe! I appended a double into an integer array despite using Math.floor, which might be it. Is there a way to convert JavaScript doubles to integer? I used Math.floor, but that seems to have floating points still.

Comment: Use the idea from Nathan: `new java.lang.Double(x).intValue();` where `x` is your variable. I don't know why he deleted the answer. Or just use `(int) x`. Note that you may want to `ceil` your double first if you want to round up.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an integer from a double, use a function like `Math.ceil` or `Math.round`. Otherwise it is ambiguous how the conversion should be done.

Comment: Except the problem I'm having is that I'm ONLY using integers, but it gives me this double to int cast error.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't have integers, everything is a floating point value. So somewhere you have some floating point value you're getting from JavaScript that you're trying to treat as an integer. Where this happens is unclear from your question.

Casting something to a class that it isn't a subclass of will fail; Double and Integer are both subclasses of Number, you can cast a Double to a Number but not to an Integer. If you have a double value you want to convert to an integer, you could call a conversion method on the object wrapper for Double:

```
new java.lang.Double(10.001D).intValue();
```

which returns the integer part and discards any fractional part.